Is it good to manage the metadata over multiple files in a multi node environment?
We have a requirement where in we have to register a database for a scheduled job , and when the job is done, we have to de-register this database for that scheduled job.
There are two ways to look at this problem:

creating a schedule for each db, which can simply delete the schedule once its execution is done.

creating a single schedule , executing for all dbs and a new metadata which contains db id's & names to work with.


What is the right design here?
If we are creating metadata, it means we are expanding the metadata route and if we are creating new schedules, we are expanding the schedules.
Any thoughts around this?
I wanted to understand the design part for this.
